# Efficient alternatives to Union statements

Tags: sql, performance, azure, union

I need to find a more efficient method of distinctly joining two sets of data from two tables. The data held in two tables that are both defragmented, compressed and indexed. The indexes of which are also defragmented and compressed. The result sets have already been limited before the union.

Example of the code in question:

```
Select * From (
        Select A.entry_id, First_name, last_name, Mobile_Phone, Email_Address, '1' As 'ownership'
            From userAddressBook As A Join collectionMapping As B On A.entry_id=B.entry_id
            Where A.UserID=@UserID And B.GroupNameID=@groupidentifier
        Union
        Select A.entry_id, First_name, last_name, Mobile_Phone, Email_Address, '0' As 'ownership'
            From userAddressBook As A Join collectionMapping As B On A.entry_id=B.entry_id
            Where A.UserID<>@UserID And B.GroupNameID=@groupidentifier
    ) As UnionTable
    Order By last_name Asc, First_name Asc, entry_id Asc
```

I am ideally looking for an alternative method that can provide the same results. I have already tried the following:

- selecting distinct from union all
- dual inserts into table variable and select distinct
- dual inserts into temporary table and select distinct
  (And variations of the above with indexes in such a way where the index is amended at the bottom only)

I am aware of unbalanced unions causing performances issue however in this instance this query will always be hit with balanced.

Any assistance on this matter would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select
    A.entry_id
    ,First_name
    ,last_name
    ,Mobile_Phone
    ,Email_Address

    ,CASE WHEN A.UserId = @UserId THEN '1' ELSE '0' END As 'ownership'

From
    userAddressBook As A
    Join collectionMapping As B
    On A.entry_id=B.entry_id
Where
    B.GroupNameID = @groupidentifier
Order By
    last_name Asc
    ,First_name Asc
    ,entry_id Asc
```

You have nearly the exact same query, using a CASE expression and doing it in a single query would make more since.